How to get jq to output a long dataset (part 2)?
Suppose I have this ndjson file:
{"id": 99, "labeled_values": [["one", "green"], ["two", "red"], ["three", "blue"]]}
{"id": 100, "labeled_values": [["four", "green"], ["five", "red"]]}

How do I get the output below (tab-separated)?  That is: id on every line, and the pairs of (value, label) flattened.
99 one green
99 two red
99 three blue
100 four green
100 five red

Here are two failed attempts:
$ cat tmp/foo.ndjson | jq -r '.id as $id | [$id, .labeled_values.[0], .labeled_values.[1]] '
[
  99,
  [
    "one",
    "green"
  ],
  [
    "two",
    "red"
  ]
]
[
  100,
  [
    "four",
    "green"
  ],
  [
    "five",
    "red"
  ]
]

$ cat tmp/foo.ndjson | jq -r '.id as $id | [$id, .labeled_values[].[0], .labeled_values[].[1]] '
[
  99,
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "green",
  "red",
  "blue"
]
[
  100,
  "four",
  "five",
  "green",
  "red"
]

This question is very related, but I still don't understand jq well enough.
A related question: how do I learn enough about the processing model of jq to understand how to break down nested structures like this into flat structures?
Most of the examples I find are flat and simple.  They pick out single fields, not nested things.

Something like this?

Amazing. If you put that as an answer, I will accept. Extra credit for a thorough explanation. For example, why "(.id)" with parentheses? I don't understand jq, and find it hard to pick up with the current docs I've read.

Or simply:
  [.id] + .labeled_values[] | @tsv


.[] will create an output for each .labeled_values.
To convert .id to a string and add a \t use a string interpolation.
Use @tsv to convert the array to tsv
"\(.id)\t\(.labeled_values[] | @tsv)"

Try it online

Why (.id)? Why in double quotes? Why back-slash-quote the ()s?

the () is part of the string interpolation, please see the added links ;)

I chose that answer because it seems much simpler and more idiomatic. I am sorry to disappoint you. It's true I would prefer more explanation on that answer. You still got an upvote, so don't feel bad.
